# JavaScript crash after removing any trivial statement

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a short JavaScript program, which works perfectly fine ONLY if I inject any trivial statement--such as var asd;--at a specific location. The program is intended to demonstrate a simple encapsulation technique.

No other locations work. ANY trivial statement works.
This is not a DOM load issue since I'm not even dealing with the DOM.

version that works: (warning, 3 alerts)
 http://jsfiddle.net/bZUm6/3/

version that does not work:
 http://jsfiddle.net/bZUm6/2/

Please note the "var asd;" in the first version.

Can someone please tell me why?
I would really appreciate it.

Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the semicolon removal that's breaking it.

It will work even if you change...

```
var asd;
```

simply to this...

```
;
```

The reason is that the next line of code starts with `(`, which happens to be wrapping a function with its closing `)`.

This is being interpreted as a function call operator, and is attempting to invoke the previous expression.

```
    MyApp.util.toXML = function(options, obj) {
        // your code

        return result.join("");
    }

//    var asd;   // removing the semicolon

//  |------seen as invoking the result of the previous expression and passing
//  v         the function as an argument. 
    (function(toXML) {

        // your code

    })(MyApp.util.toXML);
//     ^---------------^ This is then attempting to invoke the return value
//     of "toXML", which if it successfully returned, returned a String, which 
//     can't be invoked.
```

Comment: You sir have made my day. Now I must go bash my head against a pillow ... thank you very much

Comment: @Max: You're welcome. I've been there. I rarely use semicolons, and until I got used to placing a `;` at the start of any line that begins with `(`, `[` or `{`, it got me a couple times too.

Comment: Remember that variables are function scoped, and will be hoisted to the top of the function in which you define them. I personally can't wait for `let`

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
MyApp.util.toXML = function(options, obj) {
}

(function(){
}());
```

you are actually invoking the function

```
MyApp.util.toXML = function(options, obj) {
}( function(){}()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the `;` after the function definition

```
MyApp.util.toXML = function() {
 // code
}; // this semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon, that's all. See http://jsfiddle.net/bZUm6/6/ (working).

After a function assignment, never forget the `;`!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bZUm6/8/

You're missing a semicolon after the function.  I suppose it evaluates to something else if you don't end the statement.